# wxMaxima: subindexed variables in functions work when written as "x_1" but not when written as "x[1]"

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I'm having trouble defining a function in terms of variables with subindices. Using the `makelist` command I can create an unspecified function that depends upon the subindexed variables `x[1]` and `x[2]`. However, when I try to give an expression to that function, wxMaxima does not allow it:

[image]

On the other hand, if I write the subindexed variables as `x_1` and `x_2` instead of `x[1]` and `x_[2]`, things do work.

[image]

What is the reason for this behavior? Aren't the two subindexing methods equivalent in terms of functions?

Comment: Welcome! This is a pretty good question, but it's generally a good idea to share your source and output as text not a screenshot.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only symbols can be declared function arguments. In particular, subscripted expressions are not symbols and therefore can't be function arguments.

WxMaxima displays symbols which end in a number, e.g., `x_1`, the same as subscripted expressions, e.g., `x[1]`. This is intended as a convenience, although it is confusing because it makes it difficult to distinguish the two.

You can see the internal form of an expression via `?print` (note the question mark is part of the name). E.g., `?print(x_1);` versus `?print(x[1]);`.